# new magento install - how to get any product or category page to show up - anything other than the home page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, template

Bear with me as I'm new to magento and completely lost here. I'm used to php/html coding but thought this shopping cart would have allowed a regular user without any programming knowledge to create a online store -- it does have a backend that seems to bear functions that allow this at first glance. Then I downloaded latest magento CE 1.9.1.1 and installed following instructions. Installation was a breeze I admit that. But then nothing works beyond the home page.

I installed magento with the sample data provided by magento web site. So on home page, there're products showing with nice pictures etc. But the home page is the only thing that shows up. Clicking on any link gives me a 'page not found' error. For example, clicking on the "women" category (on home page), the url address showing on my browser address bar is "/women.html", which I suppose should be the category page to display women products -- keep in mind I installed original magento sample data successfully so the product/category data is indeed in database. When I looked around in magento backend - CMS page, I don't see a category template page or product page at all.

My background is from another shopping cart years ago and we used to use one html template page to use for displaying any category or product, so there's one category page, and one product page, and each is just a template so they can be used for any category or any product. I would think magento should be doing the same? WHERE exactly is this page? I did see some phtml files under "app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/" folder, which looks like what should be used -- everything I set up is in default setting so theme is also the default rwd.

Comment: Please go read some documentation; this question is way too general and could be summarized as "how do I Magento".

Comment: I've read a lot documentations, search on google as well, just couldn't find a straight answer - nobody else seems to have this problem? Please check http://45.33.121.19/ if that clarifies things. I only have a clean magento installation with sample data, I didn't edit or customize anything, everything is in default, I thought it would be a functional site out of the box but apparently not for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have your apache set up correctly. You need to route all requests through the index.php file. If you look at http://45.33.121.19/chelsea-tee-754.html there is no page found but if you route the request through index.php by putting it in the url, e.g http://45.33.121.19/index.php/chelsea-tee-754.html, there is.

There are a number of reasons this could be happening. Maybe its just your apache config, maybe you dont have the mod rewrite apache module installed.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. I knew it should be something simple / fundamental. Guess I was searching at wrong directions as I thought it was some magento setting, when in fact it's apache. It works now!! THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide the details of what I did to solve this problem -- so others may find it potentially useful

- log in to server, enable apache rewrite:
  a2enmod rewrite
- in apache conf file for the site, set permission that applies to magento folder:
  AllowOverride All
- make sure .htaccess file is in magento folder.

I didn't touch any default setting in magento as I already enabled server rewrite during installation.

THANK YOU